# Dimensional Model for inheritance in dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, inheritance, dimension

How are dimensions typically modeled in a dimensional model if one dimension logically inherits from another dimension?

For example, assume I have an `Employee` dimension and a `Driver` dimension, where the Driver has all the attributes of an Employee but also has a `Truck Number` attribute.  How should these dimensions be modelled?

Answer (score 1):

While in a traditional OLTP system you may need to be concerned about normalizing and inheritance, in a typical data warehouse system you will want to denormalize to accelerate query responses.

In this case, I would design an `Employee_Dimension` table which had all relevant columns about an employee which you might want to query against, along with an additional column which I might call `employee_role`, which I would fill in with entries like `Driver`, `Manager`, etc. and then have another column which had either the `truck_number` filled for employees who were a driver, or leave the column as `NULL` when they aren't drivers. Of course, you can add even further columns to include information for other employee roles.

Long story short, if you're building a typical star schema, you can achieve faster query results by using heavy denormalization, at the cost of storage space of course.

Comment: This ^^, except I would put in N/A or something instead of nulls for the missing attributes, See [kimball](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2010/10/design-tip-128-selecting-default-values-for-nulls/)

Answer (score 0):

hear I would employ a swappable dimension pattern.  Create three dimensions with the same SK's:

```
1) **Employee** Base table with the common attributes
2) **Driver** table with driver specific attributes note the SK' needs to match the table above
3) **DriverEmployee** a view that joins the values from one and two.
```

then when you report on the data choose the structure that best suits the requirements: Employee, Driver, DriverEmployee